# Programmatically click follows href and add some code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to dynamically add an href element (to open a jnlp file), then continue the caller's workflow, for example just doing a `console.log`.

So far, my code is this:

```
$('<a id="tmplink" />')
  .attr('href', '/open_my.jnlp')
  .text('LINK')
  .appendTo('body')
  .get(0)
  .click(function(e) {
      console.log('aaaa'); // <-- this is never reached
});
```

The jnlp file is opening, but the browser's console, at least in Firefox is refreshed/cleaned and the `console.log` is never reached.

Comment: Remove `get(0)` if you want to bind click event using jquery. `get(0)` has no meaning here

Comment: So, you are opening file in same window/tab, and page is refreshed (expected), so, code after refresh is never reached (expected, too, you have opened new file)? Prevent default, add some delay (setTimeout) and then redirect to new file, maybe?

Comment: @sinisake, hmm, so after clicking the new page has the control?, how can I let force the caller to continue in control?.

Comment: @leonardorame, not sure about context, but you can use ajax - to load new file inside existing ('caller') page, and to avoid page refresh...

Comment: @sinisake, no I cannot use Ajax, because this way the .jnlp is not handled by the browser, I mean it is loaded, but won't run.

Answer (score 2):

Your code will work fine after adjusting this two points :

1. No need to use `.get(0)` since it will return the element HTML like :

   ```
   <a id="tmplink" href="/open_my.jnlp">LINK</a>
   ```

So you cant attach click event to (`html`) instead you could attach the event `click()` directly.

2. You should prevent the redirect using `.preventDefault()` to see the console log :

   ```
   $('<a id="tmplink" />')
      .attr('href', '/open_my.jnlp')
      .text('LINK')
      .appendTo('body')
      .click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         console.log('anchor clicked');
   });
   ```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('<a id="tmplink" />')
.attr('href', '/open_my.jnlp')
.text('LINK')
.appendTo('body')
.click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('anchor clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, but i am not sure that file shouldn't be opened. This way - link doesn't work.

Comment: @sinisake exactly, this shows the console.log but doesn't follows the link, I want to do both things.

Comment: No you can't do the both thinks since the page will be redirected if you want to follows the link then the log will be automatically cleared for the new page, if you remove the `preventDefault()` you could notice that the log will be shown for a while then cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work if you add the click event listener separately, beneath the intial statement.

**Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('<a id="tmplink" />')
        .attr('href', '/open_my.jnlp')
        .text('LINK')
        .appendTo('body')
        .get(0);

    $('#tmplink').click(function(){
        console.log('aaaa');
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I wish I could, but I am in the middle of learning jQuery right now. I see that it does work, but I cannot explicitly state why.